# jBullet Camera "Holder" Is Not Moving

Tags: java, camera, bulletphysics, jbullet

I am using jBullet with OpenGL to create a basic game engine. I created two classes named `ObjectSurface` and `ObjectEntity`. Basically ObjectSurface's have no mass so they don't move and ObjectEntity's can move by collision or gravity.

I created a Camera with an ObjectEntity object named `cameraHolder` so that it can fall and have collision and all.

The problem is that the `cameraHolder` is supposed to move when the specific **WASD** key is pressed but it only moves one *unit* and doesn't move anymore. When the button is released, it moves one *unit* to the opposite direction so that you are at the same location. And after the `cameraHolder` moves the Camera's **XYZ** are set to the **XYZ** coordinates of the `cameraHolder`.

However, the movement works for the movement caused by jBullet which is falling down because of the gravity.

And when I don't use the jBullet updates, the cameraHolder moves normally. So the problem should be with the jBullet updates. *I will be showing that in the code.*

**Question:** Why is the cameraHolder only moving 1 unit and then back when the specific *WASD* buttons are pressed?

Here is the code for the movement in the `Camera.java` class:

```
public void move(float amount, float direction) {

if(!still){
    if (direction == MOVE_BACKWARD) {
        //MOVE BACKWARDS (CODE NOT NEEDED, WORKS WITHOUT CAMERA CARRIER)
        }

        if (direction == MOVE_FORWARD) {
        //MOVE FORWARD
        }

        if (direction == MOVE_LEFT) {
        //MOVE LEFT
        }

        if (direction == MOVE_RIGHT) {
        //MOVE RIGHT
        }
    }
}

public void carryCamera() {
    if(!still){
    x = cameraHolder.pos.x;
    y = cameraHolder.pos.y;
    z = cameraHolder.pos.z;
    }
}
```

Here is how an `ObjectEntity` is created:

```
private void createShape() {
    DefaultMotionState fallMotionState = new DefaultMotionState(new Transform(new Matrix4f(new Quat4f(0, 0, 0, 1), new Vector3f(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z), 1.0f)));
    Vector3f fallInertia = new Vector3f(0,0,0); 
    shape.calculateLocalInertia(mass,fallInertia); 
    RigidBodyConstructionInfo fallRigidBodyCI = new RigidBodyConstructionInfo(mass,fallMotionState,shape,fallInertia); 
    body = new RigidBody(fallRigidBodyCI); 
    Engine.getDynamicsWorld().addRigidBody(body); 
}
```

Here is how the Physics World is created:

```
private static void initPhysics() {
    BroadphaseInterface broadphase = new DbvtBroadphase();
    DefaultCollisionConfiguration collisionConfiguration = new DefaultCollisionConfiguration();
    CollisionDispatcher dispatcher = new CollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);
    SequentialImpulseConstraintSolver solver = new SequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();
    dynamicsWorld = new DiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, broadphase, solver, collisionConfiguration);
    dynamicsWorld.setGravity(Game.gravity);
}
```

How the input is gotten and physics are updated (*SUSPICIOUS CODE IS IN THIS PART*):

```
public static Vector3f gravity = new Vector3f(0, -10, 0); //GRAVITY
private ArrayList<Object> objects; //ALL THE OBJECTS IN THE GAME (CAMERAHOLDER IS IN HERE)

        //GETTING INPUT, USING move() METHOD IN CAMERA CLASS TO MOVE HOLDER.
public void getInput() {

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LCONTROL))
        speedMultiplier = 3;

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W))
        cam.move(cam.getMoveSpeed() * speedMultiplier, Camera.MOVE_FORWARD);

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S))
        cam.move(cam.getMoveSpeed() * speedMultiplier, Camera.MOVE_BACKWARD);

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))
        cam.move(cam.getMoveSpeed() * speedMultiplier, Camera.MOVE_LEFT);

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D))
        cam.move(cam.getMoveSpeed() * speedMultiplier, Camera.MOVE_RIGHT);

    cam.carryCamera(); //MOVES THE ACTUAL CAMERA TO THE HOLDER.
    speedMultiplier = 1;

}

public void update() {
    applyJBullet();
}

        //AND JBULLET PHYSICS ARE APPLIED HERE (SUSPICIOUS CODE!!!)
public void applyJBullet(){
Engine.getDynamicsWorld().stepSimulation(1/60.f, 10); //SIMULATES NEXT FRAME

    for (Object o : objects) { 
        if(o.getMass() >= 1){ //ALL THE OBJECTS WITH MASS ARE FOUND

    Transform trans = new Transform();   //CREATING A NEW TRANSFORM
    o.getBody().getMotionState().getWorldTransform(trans); //GET THE SIMULATED LOCATION

//It still doesn't work when I do: "trans.origin.x+=2" here. The same problem occurs.
    o.setPos(trans.origin); //AND SET IT AS THE OBJECTS POSITION
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better why than just using a box shape is to have a kinematic body. To turn the camera body﻿ into a 'kinematic body' (preferable one-way collision, moved by user), call the following:

```
body.setCollisionFlags(body.ge­tCollisionFlags() | CollisionFlags.KINEMATIC_OBJEC­T);
body.setActivationState(Collis­ionObject.DISABLE_DEACTIVATION­);
```